# IndexError on iterating through CSV column

Tags: python, loops, csv, exception, index-error

I'm new to python and I'm encountering an IndexError: list index out of range when running the below code. I just have an Excel spreadsheet as a .csv file and I would like to take the info from the cells and append it into an array. It prints the info I want, but it seems to fail when it hits the last row. The error tells me I went 1 past the number of rows but I'm not sure how that happens.

```
dates = []
with open('File.csv') as csvDataFile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row[1])
        dates.append(row[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your rows appear to be empty/having 1 column only. You could either use a `try-except` brace, or an `if` check.

---

**Option 1**
*EAFP*, `try-except`

```
for row in readCSV:
    try:
        print(row[1])
        dates.append(row[1])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

---

**Option 2**
`if` condition check

```
for row in readCSV:
    if row:
        print(row[1])
        dates.append(row[1])
```

Comment: Hello Coldspeed, thank you very much for the quick answer! Appreciate it!

Comment: @ontarum Well, hello to you too.

Comment: Aha, I wanted to say thank you but I didn't realize hitting enter just added the comment. Thanks again